# u-boot mmc read_block limitiations

Tags: embedded, u-boot

I am trying to copy a file from a MMC/SD card in a global variable (struct) of U-Boot SPL, which is in OCRAM. So far I am trying to use

```
mmc->block_dev.block_read(0, file_sector, 4, &my_struct);
```

Since copying to DRAM (DDR3/DDR4) works (if I replace `&my_struct` with an address in RAM, the call succeed and I can correctly read the file back from RAM), I am certain that my file is located at the beginning of sector `file_sector`.

However, with this code, I get:

```
ERROR: v7_dcache_inval_range - start address is not aligned - 0x100082f4
ERROR: v7_dcache_inval_range - start address is not aligned - 0x10008af4
```

Are there some requirements/limitations I should be aware off on the location of the destination of `block_read` ?

Comment: `mmc_read` should do its work using character buffers. It should not require any specific alignment.

Comment: What is "DDRAM" supposed to be?

Comment: My bad, this is a typo. Should read DRAM (documentation says DDR3/DDR4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, part of the answer is what it says right there in the error message.  Where 'mystruct' is, is not cache aligned so the flushing that we do isn't valid.  You should use the ALLOC_CACHE_ALIGN_BUFFER macro and as @LPs mentioned, be copying into a character buffer.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. From the doc in common.h I see that the macro is made to allocate on the stack. Is there an equivalent to allocate on the head ? I need to fill the header and read it back in two separate files.

Comment: You mean the heap?  If you have DDR initialized then yes you can use malloc_cache_aligned() from memalign.h

Comment: Yes.. heap... sorry :) Thanks for the answer !